# swift4 jsonDecoder.decode fails when the json file, placed in the main.bundle, becomes large

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I'm trying to load food data (2900 foods with 60 components), for this I create a json file and as long as the file keep small using I properly populate the struct that represent Food.

When the json file is small (20 foods) everything works perfectly
When the number of foods is larger (a few hundreds)
(i) Xcode take a long time to become reactive after I copy the json file by dragging from the desktop 
(ii) when the file is too large Xcode fails and I need to Force quit 
(iii) in other cases JSONDecoder.decode fails

is there a size limit for json file under Xcode 9 ?

Comment: I don't know about JSONDecoder. My app contains a 10 MB JSON file, and JSONSerializer has no problem opening it.